# Documenting prototype property and method with JSDoc-3.3.0-alpha5

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have a class named `FileDownloader` and I've tried documenting it, but the properties and method declared using `prototype` aren't generated in the output file.

As stated on the title, I use jsdoc 3.3.0-alpha5.

Here's the code:

```
/**
 * @class
 * @memberOf module:utils
 */
FileDownloader = function() {};    
/**
 * @type {Boolean}
 */
FileDownloader.prototype.overwrite = false;
/**
 * @type {String}
 */
FileDownloader.prototype.dir = config.dealImagePath;    
/**
 * @param {String} url
 * @param {Function} done
 * @param {Object} done.err
 * @param {String} done.file
 */
FileDownloader.prototype.download = function(url, done) {
    //...
};
```

Here is the generated document:

```
new FileDownloader()
    | Source: path/to/file.js
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is `memberOf` in FileDownloader description.
You should set module before, all symbols in the file are assumed to be members of the module.  http://usejsdoc.org/tags-module.html

Like this

```
/** @module utils */

/**
 * @class
 */
var FileDownloader = function() {};

/**
 * @type {Boolean}
 */
FileDownloader.prototype.overwrite = false;
...
```

Comment: Well, `@module utils` is defined on the other file. It works just fine when I remove the @memberOf tag though.

Comment: Do you want to set `FileDownloader` like a part of `utils` module? It seems ok to add `@module utils` in several files.

Comment: I tried putting `@module utils` in several files, but then it will produce duplicated classes of that module. For example, if I put `@module utils` to Class1.js and Class2.js, then it will output 2 Class1.js and 2 Class2.js in utils module.